# How to query in Datatable Post server-side processing?

Tags: php, mysql, json, datatable

It is possible to have a query in

https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html
at

`\\DB table to use
$table = "database_table";`

like this

`$table = "SELECT a.empid, b.status FROM dv_info a LEFT JOIN dv_form b ON a.id = b.id ORDER BY a.empid";`

Is this possible to have a query in datatable? Because I need to show many data using left join query.

```
<?php


    /*
     * DataTables example server-side processing script.
     *
     * Please note that this script is intentionally extremely simply to show how
     * server-side processing can be implemented, and probably shouldn't be used as
     * the basis for a large complex system. It is suitable for simple use cases as
     * for learning.
     *
     * See http://datatables.net/usage/server-side for full details on the server-
     * side processing requirements of DataTables.
     *
     * @license MIT - http://datatables.net/license_mit
     */

    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Easy set variables
     */

    // DB table to use
    $table = "dv_info";

    // Table's primary key
    $primaryKey = 'id_info';

    // Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
    // The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
    // parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case object
    // parameter names

    $columns = array(
        array( 'db' => 'userlevel',     'dt' => 'userlevel' ),
        array( 'db' => 'dv_no',         'dt' => 'dv_no' ),
        array( 'db' => 'payee',         'dt' => 'payee' ),
        array( 'db' => 'unit',          'dt' => 'unit' ),
        array( 'db' => 'address',       'dt' => 'address' ),
        array( 'db' => 'empid',         'dt' => 'empid' )
    );

    // SQL server connection information
    $sql_details = array(
        'user' => 'root',
        'pass' => 'pass123',
        'db'   => 'database',
        'host' => 'host'
    );



    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
     * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
     */

    require( 'ssp.class.php' );

    echo json_encode(
        SSP::simple( $_POST, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
    );




    ?>
```

Comment: no idea what your asking

Comment: user3751286, would you be willing to expand on your requirements please?